# \RLmulticolcolumns deactivated if "right to left" language is loaded with \setotherlanguage xelatex

Tags: multicol, polyglossia, right-to-left

The command `\RLmulticolcolumns` from `multicol` package to reverse order of the columns on the page from right to left work fine with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`, here a working  example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}

\RLmulticolcolumns

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The order of columns is starting here from right to left.

If we uncomment the line `\setotherlanguage{arabic}`, order of columns become starting from left to right, same thing if we replace `arabic` with `farsi` or any right to left language.

I think that the problem comes from the package `polyglossia` which change in definition of `\RLmulticolcolumns` when right to left language is defined as otherlanguage.

How to fix this problem and take advantage of the `\RLmulticolcolumns` command with right to left language set as other language, thanks.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?  This seems to work correctly for me (TL2015).

Comment: TL2015 on windows 8.1

Comment: Sorry, it worked with LuaLaTeX, but it doesn't work with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the command `\RTLmulticolcolumns` from `bidi` package instead of `\RLmulticolcolumns` from `multicol` we can obtain what we need: columns starting from right to left

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri} 

\RTLmulticolcolumns % defined from bidi package 

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Showing that `polyglossia` use `bidi` package if a right to left language is loaded as other language.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seem like `\(LR-RL)multicolcolumns` doesn't work

you can try with the command `\resetdefaultlanguage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman} 

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\resetdefaultlanguage{arabic}


\begin{multicols}{2}
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله

اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله

اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @touhami, but I would like to keep the same settings along my document, Namely :  `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` and 
`\setotherlanguage{arabic}`.

Comment: @salimbou you're right. but you still can define `myArabic` environment that make arabic as defaut at begin and reset english at end (if no other solution)

Comment: It's a good idea @touhami  but it cannot be applied in my situation to get what I want.