# Polyglossia Bug?? Multicolumn mixup when Arabic is not the main language

Tags: xetex, multicol, polyglossia, arabic

I seem to have come across an unexpected bug. When using the multicolumn package to typeset Arabic text (polyglossia with XeLatex, MiKTeX, TeXworks on Windows 10), I encounter a problem. When Arabic is set as the main (or default) language, there is no problem. The text comes out correctly. But when English is the main language, and Arabic is just another language, the columns are mishandled, and instead of the correct order, they appear reversed in the output. Below is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Lateef}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
شنّت القوات العراقية هجوما على مطار مدينة الموصل، أحد أهم أهداف العملية 
العسكرية لطرد مسلحي تنظيم الدولة الإسلامية من شطر المدينة الغربي.  كما 
اقتحمت القوات معسكر الغزلاني القريب من المطار، والذي شهد اشتباكات عسكرية 
عنيفة، بحسب وكالة أسوشيتد برس.  يشار إلى أن تنظيم الدولة قد دمّر بالفعل 
ممر الطائرات، غير أن الاستيلاء على مثل هذا الموقع المهم من شأنه مساعدة 
الجيش العراقي في السيطرة على الطرق المؤدية إلى المدينة.

واستعادت القوات العراقية والميليشيات الموالية لها الشطر الشرقي 
للمدينة، الشهر الماضي.  ويقول مراسل بي بي سي، كوينتين سومرفيل، الذي 
رافق القوات العراقية، إنهم وصلوا إلى محيط المطار.  وقال متحدث باسم 
الجيش لفضائية "العراقية" إن غارات متزامنة يُجرى شنها على المطار وقاعدة 
الغزلاني لـ "تشتيت" مسلحي تنظيم الدولة.

وكانت منشورات قد أُلقيت في وقت سابق، للتحذير من شنّ هجوم وشيك على غرب 
المدينة، الذي يقول مسؤولون عسكريون إن شوارعه المتعرجة والضيقة قد تجعل 
استعادة المنطقة مهمة صعبة. وعلى الرغم من أن غرب المدينة أصغر بقليل من 
شرقها، إلا أنه أكثر كثافة ويضم مناطق يُنظر إليها باعتبارها مؤيدة لتنظيم 
الدولة.  وأعربت الأمم المتحدة عن قلقها بشأن الأوضاع المعيشية للمدنيين 
المحاصرين في المدينة، وسط تقارير عن أن عددهم قد يرتفع إلى 650 ألفا.  
وفرّ بالفعل ما يربو على 160 ألف شخص من منازلهم داخل المدينة وحولها.  

\end{multicols}

\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

The text is adapted from a beautiful example of kashida / tatweel (http://andreasmhallberg.github.io/stretchable-kashida/). In the original example, Arabic is set as the main language, and the columns are correctly displayed in the output PDF. When Arabic is not the main language, however, the columns are incorrectly displayed, with the third column being the first column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237378/latex-issue-when-using-multicol-with-rtl-languages), you should add `\RTLmulticolcolumns`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Lateef}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}\RTLmulticolcolumns

\begin{multicols}{3}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
شنّت القوات العراقية هجوما على مطار مدينة الموصل، أحد أهم أهداف العملية 
العسكرية لطرد مسلحي تنظيم الدولة الإسلامية من شطر المدينة الغربي.  كما 
اقتحمت القوات معسكر الغزلاني القريب من المطار، والذي شهد اشتباكات عسكرية 
عنيفة، بحسب وكالة أسوشيتد برس.  يشار إلى أن تنظيم الدولة قد دمّر بالفعل 
ممر الطائرات، غير أن الاستيلاء على مثل هذا الموقع المهم من شأنه مساعدة 
الجيش العراقي في السيطرة على الطرق المؤدية إلى المدينة.

واستعادت القوات العراقية والميليشيات الموالية لها الشطر الشرقي 
للمدينة، الشهر الماضي.  ويقول مراسل بي بي سي، كوينتين سومرفيل، الذي 
رافق القوات العراقية، إنهم وصلوا إلى محيط المطار.  وقال متحدث باسم 
الجيش لفضائية "العراقية" إن غارات متزامنة يُجرى شنها على المطار وقاعدة 
الغزلاني لـ "تشتيت" مسلحي تنظيم الدولة.

وكانت منشورات قد أُلقيت في وقت سابق، للتحذير من شنّ هجوم وشيك على غرب 
المدينة، الذي يقول مسؤولون عسكريون إن شوارعه المتعرجة والضيقة قد تجعل 
استعادة المنطقة مهمة صعبة. وعلى الرغم من أن غرب المدينة أصغر بقليل من 
شرقها، إلا أنه أكثر كثافة ويضم مناطق يُنظر إليها باعتبارها مؤيدة لتنظيم 
الدولة.  وأعربت الأمم المتحدة عن قلقها بشأن الأوضاع المعيشية للمدنيين 
المحاصرين في المدينة، وسط تقارير عن أن عددهم قد يرتفع إلى 650 ألفا.  
وفرّ بالفعل ما يربو على 160 ألف شخص من منازلهم داخل المدينة وحولها.  

\end{multicols}

\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```